# Java generics parameter

Tags: java, generics

i have problem with this situation:

```
public abstract class Commune<T> {
    public abstract <T> void putSettlement(T settlement);
}



public class UrbanCommune() extends Commune{
    private Cities cities = new Cities();

    @Override
    public void putSettlement(City city) {
        cities.put(City city);
    }
}
```

I'm now learning generics, so I don't understand why it doesn't work...
How can I manage it?

Comment: Your method `putSettlement` defines an additional type parameter `T` that is different from the one on the class definition. Your method declaration should be `public abstract void putSettlement(T settlement);`

Comment: Because it's not valid Java code. Read the error messages from the Java compiler. When asking a question, don't just say "it doesn't work". Tell what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead, precisely.

Comment: You should use an IDE, like Intellij (or eclipse) it'll tell you all the errors you make

Comment: () after class name is invalid in java - class UrbanCommune()

Comment: And lookup the term "raw type".

Comment: Yeah, I know, i wrote it in hurry in buss, so i made that mistake unintentionally.
I use IntelliJ and it says, that i should change City in putSettlement to Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `T` is define as a generic for the whole class, you don't have to define it for the method too :

```
public abstract class Commune<T> {
    public abstract void putSettlement(T settlement);
}
```

---

You have to define your class as this, specifying what `T` will be in the class (and remove that `()` !) :

```
public class UrbanCommune extends Commune<City>{
    private Cities cities = new Cities();

    @Override
    public void putSettlement(City city) {
        cities.put(City city);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I made () mistake unintentionally.

I want to inherit from Commune in other class too, in UrbVillCommune, and there I want to have two methods: putSettlement(City city), and putSettlement(Village village), can i somehow do it in generics, or should I make Settlement class and in City and Village inherit from Settlement, then putSettlement(Settlement settlement) ?

Comment: @KamilBrodziak is there a link between City and Village ? inherit or something ?

Comment: No, they are similiar, but not connected.

Comment: @KamilBrodziak 2 classes which inherit fom same, with Generic, should be used to do like about the same but for different object, here it's not. Because you want one class to have 1 method, and the other have 2, you can't, you have to change your model

Comment: @KamilBrodziak if the answer if ok for you, think about accept it, or comment/edit your post o give further details